# Command Line arguments in c++

Tags: command-line, bash, c++

I wrote a c++ program. When the execution of that program, I should pass a string to that program. I executed my program as like below,

```
./sample "ball!28sweetDecay"
```

When I run this program, I got the below error message.

```
-bash: !28: event not found
```

I see some characters in my arguments as '`!28`'. Couldn't I send this string as an argument? But I must send this string as an argument? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute this command in your shell to treat `!` as regular chacter

```
set +o histexpand
```

Thus,

`./sample "ball!28sweetDecay" # will give ball!28sweetDecay`

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355797/196433